# Add Delay Element in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where I need to add delay in between messages.

Imagine the messages as chat messages.`var object = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];` these are the five messages and number 3 is the delay message.

When I reach 3 I need to show typing.. for  lets say 2s. and after that 4 and 5 should show.

Here is what I try:

```
var object = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

 for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
                if (object[i] == 3) {   
                    $('div').append('typing');                
                   sleep(2);

                }
                console.log(object[i]);
   }



function sleep(seconds) {
        var waitUntil = new Date().getTime() + seconds * 1000;
        while (new Date().getTime() < waitUntil) true;
    }
```

My current problem is the `div` is appending after 2 second not before the delay start.

Why this happen? What is the solution?

Please help Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are looking for `setTimeout` and `setInterval`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)

Comment: can you please help .not sure why you say duplicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep

Comment: how can i achieve  set timeout inside the loop because i need to hauls the exec if i was not wrong.

Comment: You need to convert your for loop into a recursive loop, where setTimeout recursively calls a method with the next element to append, until they have all been appended

Comment: highly appreciate if you can write the code of the above idea. @Taplar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Created method `appendTyping` that is executed immediately, passing in the array and index 0
2. Function executes its logic
3. At the end, if the next index is still within the bounds of the array, we perform the setTimeout to wait to start the next iteration.

```js
var elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

(function appendTyping (elements, index) {
  var element = elements[index];
  
  if (element == 3) $('div').append('typing');
  else console.log(element);
  
  if (++index < elements.length) {
    setTimeout(function(){ appendTyping(elements, index); }, 2000);
  }
})(elements, 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive functions (a function that call itself) with setTimeout.
[Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

/*for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
  numbers.push(i)
}*/

function doLogic(numbers, index) {
  setTimeout( function() {
      
      if( index >= numbers.length ) { // stop condition
        console.log("DONE")
        return;
      }
    
      /*
       * make logic here
       */
      
      console.log("LOGIC: " + numbers[index] )
      return doLogic(numbers, index+1)
      
  }, 1000 )
}

doLogic(numbers, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from Tapler ,slight modification here is my answer

```
var elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8];

(function appendTyping(elements, index) {
                var element = elements[index];

                if (++index <= elements.length) {
                    if (element == 3 || element == 6) {
                        $('div').append('typing....');
                        console.log(element);
                        setTimeout(function () { appendTyping(elements, index); }, 2000);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('div').append(index);
                        console.log(element);
                        appendTyping(elements, index);
                    }
                }


            })(elements, 0);
```